# Increasing timeout for vetx server

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient, vertx-eventbus, vertxoptions

I am using a vertx server v3.7.0 as a gateway for my application.I have one service which takes more than 2 min to process data( I have few other services which takes more than 2 min ) . When I directly call that service using endpoint of the services it works fine. But similar thing when I try from vertx gateway it times out and gives **504 Gateway Time-out**.

I read on the vertx documentation section that **default timeout is 30 sec**. ( https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_sending_with_timeouts ). Do we have same for vertx gateway ? I tried to look for similar property to put into json configuration but could not find any relevant documentation for the same.

How can we configure the value of this timeout ?

Comment: `504` most probably comes from your load balancer, and not from Vert.x

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Yes you are right. Took a long time for me to realize that its from nginx server not from vertx server. Thanks for pointing out.